# Gmail Forwarding and filtering on the destination account

Tags: email, gmail, forwarding

1. I have a main gmail account where I forward emails from my other side-gmail accounts.
2. Let's say my main email is: `main.email@gmail.com`, and my side email is: `side.email@gmail.com`.
3. Now, I have set up forwarding on `side.email@gmail.com` to forward all emails to `main.email@gmail.com`.
4. I have created a filter to: `side.email@gmail.com` on `main.email@gmail.com` so that I can check all the emails from my main emails.
5. I use gmail's [dots don't matter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en) feature and register on websites as `sideemail@gmail.com` (notice the lack of the dot) or `si.deemail@gmail.com` and all these emails land in `side.email@gmail.com` just fine.

Now the issue:

- when these emails arrive to the `main.email@gmail.com` account after being forwarded from `side.email@gmail.com` as they should, there is no way for me to write a filter that encompasses all the combinations in which `side.email@gmail.com` could be written by switching the dots around. I would like to find out how I can make it so that any email sent to `side.email@gmail.com` or its "dot-switched" versions lands in one single filter on `main.email@gmail.com`

Comment: Err... you may want to re-read the dots don't matter in gmail. Basically ANY dots anywhere on your email does not matter. sideemail@gmail.com or side.email or s.i.d.e.e.m.a.i.l@gmail.com all will go into sideemail@gmail.com (or in your case side.email@gmail.com). So you don't need to worry about any filtering as all those emails will arrive in the side.email@gmail.com.

Comment: @Darius I am aware of that. The main question is 

"I would like to find out how I can make it so that any email sent to side.email@gmail.com or its "dot-switched" versions lands in one single filter on main.email@gmail.com"

Comment: My understanding is if you "Forward" the email from side.email@gmail.com then on your main.email@gmail.com - all of them will come "from: side.email@gmail.com" as the side.email is doing the email sending/forwarding. So on your main.email@gmail.com you can filter for side.email@gmail.com and all of them will fall into a single filter. But to be honest I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: but they don't come from "side.email@gmail.com". That's the issue. You receive the email just as you would on side.email@gmail.com's page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (untested suggestion):
Forward to plussed version version of your gmail address and filter based on `deliveredto`.

1. `side.email@gmail.com` forwards to `main.email+side.email@gmail.com`
2. `main.email@gmail.com` uses `deliveredto:main.email+side.email@gmail.com` in filtering

**WARNING**: email to both addresses may produce unwanted results.